# How do you tell a Clang CompilerInvocation to use a framework?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I have code that builds a `CompilerInvocation` with the Clang static libraries. I would like to tell that invocation to use specific frameworks, just like using the `-framework` Clang front-end option. In particular, I'm looking for these "side effects" of using a framework:

- the compiler locates the framework on the system using the framework search path;
- the compiler knows where to find framework headers identified through a path like `<Framework/Header.h>`.

At this point, I think that I've looked everywhere in the option sub-objects of the `CompilerInvocation` class, and the closest thing that I can identify related to that is the header search path. I can't seem to find a way to tell the `CompilerInvocation` to look for a specific framework.

How is that supposed to happen? I'm using a manually-built `CompilerInvocation` instead of building it through command-line arguments because that seems to be the only way to pass a memory buffer as a source unit instead of a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the way to do it through the `CompilerInvocation` object, but you can get a `CompilerInvocation` from command-line arguments using `clang:: createInvocationFromCommandLine`. When using `-framework` arguments, the resulting invocation can correctly `#include` framework headers. This isn't awesome, but it works (other than the compiler will complain that the frameworks are unused linker input, probably because no linking phase occurs).

Of course, this means that a way through the `CompilerInvocation` *has* to exist, because that's the only thing that's returned. I could believe that the logic to get frameworks from the framework path is private, though.